# The minimizer of $2$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to compute 
$$
\operatorname{argmin}_{z\in\mathbb R^n}\frac12\|z-x\|_2^2+\|z\|_2
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the usual 2-norm.

By doing sub-differential with respect to $z$ and let it equal to 0, I got
$$
z(1+1/\|z\|_2)=x
$$
I am wondering is this all I can do? or could I future simplify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing the prox-operator of the $\ell_2$-norm.

The Moreau decomposition formula expresses the prox-operator of a proper closed convex function $f$ in terms of the prox-operator of $f^*$, the convex conjugate of $f$:
$$
\text{prox}_{f}(x) = x -  \text{prox}_{f^*}(x).
$$
If $f(x) = \| x \|$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is any norm on $\mathbb R^n$, then $f^*$ is the indicator function for the dual norm unit ball.  It follows that the prox-operator of $f^*$ simply projects onto the dual norm unit ball. Hence,
$$
\text{prox}_{\| \cdot \|}(x) = x - P_B(x),
$$
where $B$ is the dual norm unit ball and $P_B(x)$ is the projection of $x$ onto $B$.

In the special case where $\| \cdot \|$ is the $\ell_2$-norm, $B$ is the $2$-norm unit ball (because the $\ell_2$-norm is self-dual) .  So,
$$
\text{prox}_{\| \cdot \|_2}(x) = x - P_B(x),
$$
where $B = \{u \mid \| u \|_2 \leq 1\}$.

The prox-operator of the $\ell_2$-norm simply shrinks $x$ towards by origin by a distance of one unit.

Comment: I see. So if I am computing $\operatorname{argmin}_{z\in\mathbb R^n}\frac12\|z-x\|_2^2+t\|z\|_2$ then I should expect that $\operatorname{prox}_f(x) = x-\frac1t\operatorname{prox}_{f^*}(x)$ right?

Comment: ops, it should be $t\operatorname{prox}_{f^*}(x/t)$.

Comment: @JumpJump In that case, the formula to use is $\operatorname{prox}_{tf}(x) = x - t \operatorname{prox}_{(1/t) f^*}(x/t)$.  If $f(x) = \| x \|_2$, it turns out that $\operatorname{prox}_{tf}(x)$ shrinks $x$ towards the origin by a distance $t$.

Comment: understood. thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

The formula implies that $z = tx$ for some $t$. Put that into your formula and cancels $x$, and help you solves for $t$. Then $z = tx$ is found explicitly.